# Detecting and using same link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a product split into two sections: Image and Description. The image is linked using  however the Description is not. since it is dynamic I am wondering how can I get this URL and using JS to assign it to the description box?

```
    <div class="item__media">
    <div class="item__image">
        <a href="http://prototype.aaa.com" title="" class="product-image item__link">
            <img src="http://a4.res.cloudinary.com//image/upload/c_pad,dpr_1.0,f_auto,h_221,q_80,w_303/damson_108170_1_2_2.jpg" alt="image">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item__detail">
        <a href="http://prototype.aaa.com" title="Description" class="item__link">
            <p class="product-name item__name">Product 15252</p>
        </a>

</div> </div></div>
        <div class="price-box">
            <p class="old-price">
            <span class="price-label">Was</span>
            <span class="price" id="old-price-7139">
                                <span class="price"><span class="currency">£</span>179</span>            </span>
        </p>

        <p class="special-price">
            <span class="price-label">You Save</span>
            <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-7139">
                <span class="price"><span class="currency">£</span>90</span>            </span>
        </p>
    </div>

<div class="price-range">
            <span class="price-label" style="display: none;">From </span><span class="price-label">SHOP FROM</span>
        <span class="price"><span class="price"><span class="currency">£</span>89</span></span>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks N

Comment: What have you tried? [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm pretty sure atleast one other person has tried and _possibly_ successfully solved your issue. We are **not** here to code for you.

Comment: Try looking [here](http://google.co.uk)

Comment: We are not here to code **for** you. Comeback when you have found something and attempted it.